# Where is the kingslayer's hideout?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm supposed to go to the kingslayer's hideout now, as part of the Assasins of Kings quest, but I just can't find it. The quest marker points to a cave system near the army camp, but the hideout is nowhere to be seen there. The hideout itself has a very recognizable door (as you saw in the vision), so it should be easy to identify once you found it.

Am I not looking thoroughly enough or is the quest marker in the wrong place?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the quest marker is just wrong. The hideout is deep in the south, see Geralt's position in the following map for the true location of the Kingslayer's hideout.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Thinking 1440 made this nice screenshot:](http://thinking1440.blogspot.com/2011/05/witcher-2-go-to-kingslayers-hideout-hd.html)

[image]

or go directly to the video which shows how to get there within 1 min, I wasted an hour on this till I saw the video

you can check that same blog as it is a good resource for most places you'll get stuck, it's helped me a lot